# mySQL remove row

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have run into problems trying to delete a row in a mySQL database.

The SQL method in my Java is

```
@Override
public void removeCustomerByID(int customerID) throws StorageException {

    try {
        connect();

        String sq1 = "DELETE FROM Customer WHERE ID ='"+customerID+"'";
         int deleteRow = stmt.executeUpdate(sq1); 

         if(deleteRow == 1) {
             System.out.println("Row was deleted");
         } else {
             System.out.println("Row was not deleted");
         }
    } catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        throw new StorageException("Unable to get Customer", ex);
    } finally
    {
        disconnect();
    }
}
```

And the method calling it

```
 @Test
public void testDeleteCustomer() throws StorageException {
    Customer custom = new Customer("Allan", "Jensen", 12345677);

    assertEquals(81, Main.db.getCustomerIDByNameAndPhone(custom));
    Main.db.removeCustomerByID(custom.getCustomerID());
    assertEquals(-1, Main.db.getCustomerIDByNameAndPhone(custom));
}
```

As you can see, I've set it to return -1 (hence why I assert it equals -1) when no customer is found, but it still returns 81. The Main.db. is where I access my Database class and calls it's methods.

Comment: Try removing `'` from the DELETE query, like `"DELETE FROM Customer WHERE ID ="+customerID` because it is an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

I would not pass the parameter directly into the query, I would change stmnt to be a type of PreparedStatement and not statement. Try writing it like this

```
//You obviously have these defined somewhere
PreparedStatement pstmnt = null;
Connection con = null;

String sq1 = "DELETE FROM Customer WHERE ID = ?";
pstmnt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmnt.setString(1, customerID);
pstmnt.executeUpdate();
con.commit()//If you have not set auto commit
```

Comment: +1 for `PreparedStatement` which avoids some terrible security issue

Answer (score 0):

So your main problem is the row is not getting deleted from the database. Correct me if I am wrong.

Can you please check, when you have created the connection using mysql driver what is the transaction state. I mean did you set connection.autoCommit(true). Please set this and then check. I think your delete statement is not getting committed.